# Retrieving data from a dynamically generated PL/SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle

I’ve been trying to retrieve some daily generated data but I’m having trouble figuring out how to dynamically set a daily-created table name in the FROM clause (Oracle db).  Each day a new table is generated with a date stamp as part of the table name. This will used in a daily scheduled report that must always pull from the current day’s table (i.e. today’s table name = “STATDB01.A150417001_AINF” where ‘150417’ is the current date). How can I retrieve data from the new daily table without having to update my query each day?

I can create the new table mane dynamically in the SELECT statement but I can’t get it to work in the FROM statement.

Here’s my query:

```
SELECT
    sta.statist  “Stats”
    ,sta.indept   “Department”
    ,sta.ondate   “Date”
    ,sta.skitem   “SKU”
    --< I can get this to work in the SELECT clause >--
    ,'STATDB01.A'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD')||'001_AINF' “New Table”

FROM
    --< Calling the table directly works fine >--
    --STATDB01.A150417001_AINF sta
    --< but this does not work in the FROM clause >--
    'STATDB01.A'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYMMDD')||'001_AINF'

WHERE
    sta.run_stat LIKE '%341%'

ORDER BY 
    sta.elap_time
;
```

Comment: What do you do with the data then? When you select the data, where does it go to?

Comment: The output is sent to a distribution list as a daily emailed report.

Comment: Consider to use partitioning on the table. I don't think the table contains millions of rows when you are able to send it out by mail

Comment: That's not what I meant. What is the next, immediately following step in the data distribution workflow? Do you open a cursor somewhere and fetch the data from it or do you do something else? Why can't the said report fetch data from an arbitrarily named table?

Answer (score 1):

You could write (some part of) your report in PL/sql, build your query (including the table name of the day) into a string variable, and run your query-in-a-string with [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm).

Alternatively, you could write a shell script and have it output the query with the table name of the day, and feed that (into a file if needed and then) into `sqlplus`.

Edit: By request, an [example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDGJEGD) of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in action.

Comment: I added an example. You have demonstrated that you have the other pieces you need - you know how to concatenate strings in sql, you know how to generate the dynamic file name. If you need or want to go the shell script route instead, I would need to know what platform and shell you are looking to use.